# CSS background image shows only sometimes? On and off

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a Pokemon demo, which I finished. Then a friend told me he couldn't see the character, and another also.

Now I have tested on multiple browsers and different OSes and can confirm it appears sometimes and not others. Even reloading the page and removing/adding css properties (just ticking them on/off in dev tools) can cause it to appear.

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/EPGBNb?editors=0110

```
.player {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 32px 32px;
  transition: margin 0.35s linear;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/NstnP8t.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.player.down {
  background-position: -324px -36px;
}
.player.up {
  background-position: -324px -54px;
}
.player.left {
  background-position: -306px -144px;
}
.player.right {
  background-position: -306px -144px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.player.upAnim {
  animation: upAnim 0.35s steps(1) forwards;
}
.player.downAnim {
  animation: downAnim 0.35s steps(1) forwards;
}
.player.leftAnim {
  animation: leftAnim 0.35s steps(1) forwards;
}
.player.rightAnim {
  animation: rightAnim 0.35s steps(1) forwards;
}
```

Comment: There's no markup here to reproduce the problem, linking to a codepen is not good enough.

Comment: Im on Chrome 48 Windows Vista and I can't see any character. I'm glad there is a button to stop the music.